# Alarm in pyTelegram Bot

Tags: python, time, alarm, python-telegram-bot

I want to write a simple reminder-bot for telegram. Bot gets from user time (Hours:Minutes) and saves it. When system time equals to users remind time, bot sends message to user.

This is how i track current time:

```
import time

def timer():
    now = time.strftime('%X').split(':')[0:2]
    return now
```

The question is:
How can I make my code wait till time to send message comes without using **time.sleep()** and checking current time each minute (uses too much memory of raspberrypi)?

Answer (score 0):

If you use [`python-telegram-bot`](http://python-telegram-bot.org) library, you can use the `JobQueue` to set up timed jobs.

See [here](https://github.com/python-telegram-bot/python-telegram-bot/blob/master/examples/timerbot.py) for an example.